# Testing if an element has a certain class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to test for the presence of class `intra-field-label` on an element. This element *will* have multiple classes. How may I do this?

Comment: Don't feel bad but before posting it on stackoverflow, make sure that question you are posting worth posting on stackoverflow, bcoz you can easily get the solution using google also.

Comment: Before Google, you should probably consult the actual [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `hasClass()`

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("#yourelementid").hasClass("intra-field-label")) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, there's also [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) which takes any jQuery selector. This is more flexible, but for your particular case, [Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467656/testing-if-an-element-has-a-certain-class-with-jquery/5467663#5467663) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery selector for class is ".class", http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

```
$('.intra-field-label')
```