# How do I detect a specific HTML component class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I am trying to find out if one class of my HTML component is "btnLecture". It works fine with Firefox, but it fails for Chrome or Safari.

Code:

```
btnP.on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var currentLine = event.currentTarget;

    var elementClass = $(this).attr("class");

    if (elementClass.contains("btnLecture")) {
        ...
```

Comment: The jQuery `contains` method is used on elements, and tells whether the text content of the element contains the string. It's not used on strings (but it sounds like Firefox extends the String class to include this method). See Moby's Stunt Double's answer for the fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing if an element has a certain class with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467656/testing-if-an-element-has-a-certain-class-with-jquery)

Comment: @Barmar: jQuery does indeed have a [`contains` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/), but it does not do what you described. You probably meant the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this to fix your code:

```
if (elementClass.indexOf("btnLecture") > -1)
```

But you'd probably be better off with:

```
if($(this).hasClass("btnLecture"))
```